# PyPi download counts seem unrealistic

Tags: python, web-crawler, pypi

I put [a package on PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/powerlaw) for the first time ~2 months ago, and have made some version updates since then. I noticed this week the download count recording, and was surprised to see it had been downloaded hundreds of times. Over the next few days, I was more surprised to see the download count increasing by sometimes hundreds *per day*, even though this is a niche statistical test toolbox. In particular, older versions of package are continuing to be downloaded, sometimes at higher rates than the newest version.

What is going on here?

Is there a bug in PyPi's downloaded counting, or is there an abundance of crawlers grabbing open source code (as mine is)?

Comment: congratulations!  i don't see that behaviour for my packages...  i see some bot downloads, but not that many (maybe 10-100 on a new release?).  maybe you really do have users?!  powerlaws are pretty fashionable...

Comment: They can't possibly be this fashionable! I also uploaded [another](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/avalanchetoolbox), VERY specialized scientific analysis package (avalanchetoolbox) at the same time, which has very similar behavior (>1,000 downloads in 1.5 months across all versions). There are not 1,000 people in the world that would find that package interesting, so something must be awry. 

As avalanchetoolbox relies on powerlaw, perhaps a single person actually interested in the package set up a cron job to automatically check for and download updates, and the job is buggy?

Comment: Sorry, late for tea, but stackoverflow is kind of timeless, isn't it? I noticed, that PyPI offers a windows .exe binary and only the tar.gz package format as source packaging format for your powerlaw package. If you would offer .zip, .tar.bz2 and .tar.gz (all as source formats) instead, you might obtain *some* hint by subtracting a bit. **Hypothesis**: Windows user take .zip. Most .tar.gz and .tar.bz2 equal number downloads could stem from mirroring. Makes sense?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is kind of an old question at this point, but I noticed the same thing about a package I have on PyPI and investigated further. It turns out PyPI keeps reasonably detailed [download statistics](http://pypi.python.org/stats/), including (apparently slightly anonymised) user agents. From that, it was apparent that most people downloading my package were things like "z3c.pypimirror/1.0.15.1" and "pep381client/1.5". (PEP 381 describes a mirroring infrastructure for PyPI.)

I wrote [a quick script](https://gist.github.com/Cairnarvon/4715057) to tally everything up, first including all of them and then leaving out the most obvious bots, and it turns out that **literally 99%** of the download activity for my package was caused by mirrorbots: 14,335 downloads total, compared to only 146 downloads with the bots filtered. And that's just leaving out the very obvious ones, so it's probably still an overestimate.

It looks like the main reason PyPI needs mirrors is because it has them.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/stats/ seems to have received its last update in May 2013.

Comment: How can I figure out my *real* downloads now that the states page is down? According to a user in #python it's due to the change to a CDN for downloading packages.

Comment: The link seems to be dead :(

Comment: I'm having the same confusion and the stats doesn't seem to exist any more :/

Comment: See here on why the link no longer works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531231/total-downloads-of-module-missing-on-pypi

Answer (score 11):

You also have to take into account that virtualenv is getting more popular. If your package is something like a core library that people use in many of their projects, they will usually download it multiple times.

Consider a single user has 5 projects where he uses your package and each lives in its own virtualenv. Using pip to meet the requirements, your package is already downloaded 5 times this way. Then these projects might be set up on different machines, like work, home and laptop computers, in addition there might be a staging and a live server in case of a web application. Summing this up, you end up with many downloads by a single person.

Just a thought... perhaps your package is simply good. ;)

Comment: See reply to Andrew Cooke's comment; Package B relies on Package A, so if Package B is popular that makes sense, but the content of Package B is just flatly not that popular.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Cairnarvon's summarizing statement:

> "It looks like the main reason PyPI needs mirrors is because it has them."

I would slightly modify this:

> It might be more the **way** PyPI actually works and thus has to be mirrored, that might contribute an additional bit (or two :-) to the *real* traffic.

At the moment I think you MUST interact with the main index to know what to update in your repository. State is not simply accesible through timestamps on some publicly accessible folder hierarchy. So, the bad thing is, rsync is out of the equation. The good thing is, you MAY talk to the index through JSON, OAuth, XML-RPC or HTTP interfaces.

For XML-RPC:

```
$> python
>>> import xmlrpclib
>>> import pprint
>>> client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://pypi.python.org/pypi')
>>> client.package_releases('PartitionSets')
['0.1.1']
```

For JSON eg.:

```
$> curl https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PartitionSets/0.1.1/json
```

If there are approx. 30.000 packages hosted [[1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)] with some being downloaded 50.000 to 300.000 times a week [[2](http://pypi-ranking.info/week)] (like distribute, pip, requests, paramiko, lxml, boto, paramike, redis and others) you really need mirrors at least from an accessibilty perspective. Just imagine what a user does when `pip install NeedThisPackage` fails: *Wait*? Also company wide PyPI mirrors are quite common acting as proxies for otherwise unrouteable networks. Finally not to forget the wonderful multi version checking enabled through virtualenv and friends. These all are IMO legitimate and potentially wonderful uses of packages ...

In the end, you never know what an agent *really* does with a downloaded package: Have N users really use it or just overwrite it next time ... and after all, IMHO package authors should care more for **number and nature of uses**, than the pure *number of potential users* ;-)

---

Refs: The guestimated numbers are from https://pypi.python.org/pypi (29303 packages) and http://pypi-ranking.info/week (for the weekly numbers, requested 2013-03-23).

Comment: So what you're saying is, I should make it so my package phones home everytime it's used if I want to know how many users I have. (Kidding.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare No, I would suggest to rather ignore the fuzzy part, like we implementers do it albeit seldom with races and skipped corner cases in our code: „looks good, works! Next() ...“ ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Hypothesis: CI tools like Travis CI and Appveyor also contribute quite a bit. It might mean that each commit/push leads to a build of a package and the installation of everything in requirements.txt

Answer (score -1):

### [2023] Realistic Pypi stats with and without mirrors

Many of the downloads may be by pypi mirrors. I found **https://pypistats.org/** to give a very realistic count and distinction between mirror downloads and user downloads.