# Total Downloads of Module Missing on PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

Up until recently, it was possible to see how many times a python module indexed on https://pypi.python.org/pypi had been downloaded (each module listed downloads for the past 24hrs, week and month). Now that information seems to be missing.

Download numbers are very helpful information when evaluating whether to build code off of one module or another. They also seem to be referenced by sites such as https://img.shields.io/

Does anyone know what happened? And/or, where I can view/retrieve that information?

Answer (score 10):

This [email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2016-May/028967.html) from Donald Stufft (PyPI maintainer) from `distutils` mailing list says:

> Just an FYI, I've [disabled](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/commits/f54a11a2842e687e8de01761a8ff8ceac076386c) download counts on PyPI for the time being. The statistics stack is broken and needs engineering effort to fix it back up to deal with changes to PyPI. It was suggested that hiding the counts would help prevent user confusion when they see things like "downloaded 0 times" making people believe that a library has no users, even if it is a significantly downloaded library.
>
> I'm unlikely to get around to fixing the current stack since, as part of Warehouse, I'm working on a *new* statistics stack which is much better. The data collection and storage parts of that stack are already done and I just need to get querying done (made more difficult by the fact that the new system queries can take 10+ seconds to complete, but can be queried on any dimension) and a tool to process the historical data and put it into the new storage engine.
>
> Anyways, this is just to let folks know that this isn't a permanent loss of the feature and we won't lose any data.

So i guess we'll have to wait for a new stats stack in PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Helps clarify both the reason and the situation. Waiting underway...

Answer (score 6):

I just released http://pepy.tech/ to view the downloads of a package. I use the official data which is stored in BigQuery. I hope you will find it interesting :-)

Also the site is open source https://github.com/psincraian/pepy

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what happened (although it [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376429/number-of-installations-statistics-for-pypi-packages), [i.e.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648015/pypi-download-counts-seem-unrealistic)) but you might wan't to try the [PyPI ranking](http://pypi-ranking.info/week), or any of the several available modules and recipes to do this. For example:

- [Vanity](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vanity)
- [pyStats](https://github.com/abakan/pypstats)
- [random recipe](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/pypi-download-stats/)

But consider that a lot of the downloads might be mirrors and not necessarily "real" user downloads. You should that into account in you evaluation. The libs mailing list (or other preferred media) might be a better way to know what version you should install.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Installed vanity and gave it a go. Vanity reports PyPi Stats are down. So, apparently it is a global problem. Thanks again for the list of tools.

Answer (score 1):

PYPI count is disable temporarily as posted by dmand but there are some sites which may tells you python package statistics like [pypi-stats.com](http://www.pypi-stats.com/) *(they said it shows real time information)* and [pypi-ranking.info](http://pypi-ranking.info/) *(this might not gives you real time information)*.

You can also found some pypi packages which can gives you downloads information.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. PyPi-stats is a nice temporary solution.

Comment: Unfortunately as of 2022, pypi-stats says 'this domain is for sale' and pypi-ranking is a 404.

Answer (score -1):

### [2023] download counts with and without mirrors

Since many of the links above are outdated (07/2023), I was happy to see that **https://pypistats.org/** gives what seems like a very realistic count and even has a distinction between mirror downloads and user downloads.